# HIbernate ConverterNotFoundException - SUM SQL functions

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I updated my application to Spring Boot 3 but now I have an issue with repository calls and SQL functions:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [xx.xxx.xxx.Price]
```

This error comes up by using the SUM function:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(x.price)" ....);
```

The price has an AttributeConverter. It happens only by using the SUM function. Behind the Price object a BigDecimal is used.

Converter of Price object:

```
package converter;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import jakarta.persistence.Converter;


@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class PriceConverter implements AttributeConverter<Price, BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convertToDatabaseColumn(Price attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return attribute.getPrice();
    }

    @Override
    public Price convertToEntityAttribute(BigDecimal dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Price(dbData);
    }

}
```

POM of spring boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Please add pom, the AttributeConverter code (if custom) and how the converter is configured to convert price. This **may** me javax.persistence->jakarta.persistence issue.

Comment: @JohnWilliams I added the converter in the first post because of character limits. The conveter has the Annotation "@Converter(autoApply = true)".

I changed all imports from javax.* to jakarta.*

Comment: The Converter seems to work, because I use the object on many other parts on the software. Only the SUM function in the repository does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is regression (or at best a breaking change) in SpringBoot 3.x.

In both 2.7.9 & 3.0.4 Spring locates the appropriate converter by using the sourceType and targetType.

In SpringBoot 2.7.9 (with javax.persistence) it works out that the sourceType of SUM(x.price) is BigDecimal from the column type of price. **In SpringBoot 3.0.4 (with jakarta.persistence) it uses a sourceType of org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.TupleImpl**. Obviously there is no converter registered for org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.TupleImpl -> Price.

This may be intentional. The expectation being that the code should contain another mechanism to specify the types for aggregates but I find no documentation mentioning this.

All I can suggest is the following workaround.

Repo:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(x.price) FROM Person x")
public Optional<BigDecimal> getAggregatePriceSum();
```

Annotate `PriceConverter` with `@Component`

Service:

```
@Autowired
PriceConverter priceConverter;
...
    public Price getAggregatePriceSum() {
        return priceConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(repo.getAggregatePriceSum().get());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Unfortunately now the BigDecimal returned from the Repository is without any digits behind the comma. So for example 5.30 will returned as 5. Any idea why this happen? The BigDecimal has a scale of 2 by debugging it. Is this the reason?

Comment: Additional information: The issue comes only up by using SUM() function. 

I posted a wrong information. The scale is 0 not 2 during debugging.

Comment: Is there in the meantime a way how to handle this without this workaround?

Comment: @Thomas not as far as I am aware.